# What time does a 12-hour clock read:?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> What time does a 12-hour clock read
>
> a) 80 hours after it reads 11:00?
>
> b) 40 hours before it reads 12:00?
>
> c) 100 hours after it reads 6:00?

The solution

a. (11 + 80) mod 12 = 7

b. (12 + 40) mod 12 = 4

c. (100+ 6) mod 12 = 10

How can I calculate to get 7 for a?

**Edit** I figured it out that they use the remainder right?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig No, part (b) is incorrect. You need to subtract 40 rather than adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you divide $11+80=91$ by $12$, you get $7$ *with a remainder of* $7$. Because the *remainder* is $7$, we say that
$$
(11+80) \bmod 12= 7
$$

Answer (score 2):

In non-modular arithmetic language:

After 12 hours, clock reaches back to 11. So we find number of "12" hours in 80 hours =$6\times12=72$

There's remaining $8$hours which pushes clock handle from 11 to 7 (11,12,1,2,....,7)

Answer (score 0):

Find the maximum multiple of $12$ not exceeding the given number: $$11+80 = 91 = 84+7 = 7\cdot 12+7$$

Dropping the multiple of $12$ we get $$11+80 = 7 \cdot 12 + 7 \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$$